# Sqlite query from mutliple databases which are already existing

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having difficulty in converting below sqlite query into Android source code.

I have two databases: 
  - db1 : program table
  - db2 : event table

Here is the query:

> sqlite3 db1.db

attach database '/data/data/com.stack.test/db2.db' as db2;

select a.show_id from main.program a inner join db2.event b on b.program_id = a.program_id group by a.show_id;

the query above works fine and i get the desired output.

I am having difficulty in converting this query into android java code.
The DBs are already created. I just want to open them and query.

Here is my code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = getDatabaseOpener().getWritableDatabase();         <-- this returns db1

    String attachDb = "attach database '" + "/data/data/com.stack.test/db2.db" + "' as db2";
    mDb.execSQL(attachDb);


    String tables = "main.program INNER JOIN db2.event ON db2.event.program_id=main.program.program_id";

    String groupBy = "main.program.show_id";

    String rawShowsQuery = SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(false, tables,
            SHOWS_PROJECTION, null, groupBy, null, null, null);

    try (Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(rawShowsQuery, null)) {
        if (cursor == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting following error :

E/SQLiteDatabase( 9952): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.stack.test/db2.db'.
E/SQLiteDatabase( 9952): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

If attaching db2 to db1 connected worked in the command line, then if should have worked here in the code as well right ?
Am i missing something in the code ?

Comment: I have two databases 1) db1 has program table, and 2) db2 has event table

Comment: Use sqlitehelper to simplify life. Calling the data/data/package... is not advised!

Comment: Add this permission to your project's AndroidManifest.xml file   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @RatilalChopda. I added the permission for both read and write. But i am still getting the same error about "Failed to open database ..."

Comment: better use single database with multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully working example (albeit with 3 attached for demonstration purposes and perhaps overly complicated due to column name duplication) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DBNAME1 = "db1";
    public static final String DBNAME2 = "db2";
    public static final String DBNAME3 = "db3";
    public static final String ID_COLUMN = "_id";
    public static final String TABLENAME_BASE = "_table_main";
    public static final String NAMECOLUMN_BASE = "_name";
    public static final String DB2_COL_NAME = DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;
    public static final String EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME = DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE;
    public static final String EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME = DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE;
    public static final String DB2_FULL_IDCOL = EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME + "." + ID_COLUMN;
    public static final String DB2_FULL_NAMECOL = EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME + "." + DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;
    public static final String DB3_FULL_IDCOL = EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME + "." + ID_COLUMN;
    public static final String DB3_FULL_NAMECOL = EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME + "." + DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;

    private static final String[] DB1NAMES = new String[] {"Fred","Bert","Harry","Tom","Dick"};
    private static final String[] DB2NAMES = new String[] {"Alan","George","Robert","Colin","Ian","John"};

    String mDB1Path, mDB2path;
    SQLiteDatabase mMaster;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB1Path = createDatbase(DBNAME1);
        mDB2path = createDatbase(DBNAME2);

        // Check that can be added for those who are too arrogant to
        // even consider they may have the incorrect path name coded
        // when hard coding the path rather than obtaining it via code.
        Log.d("DBPATHS","Path for " + DBNAME1 + " is " + mDB1Path);
        Log.d("DBPATHS","Path for " + DBNAME2 + " is " + mDBPath2);

        /* Only uncomment for first run to populate database tables
        for (String s: DB2NAMES) {
            insertRow(DBNAME1,s);
        }
        for (String s: DB1NAMES) {
            insertRow(DBNAME2,s);
        }
        */

        mMaster = this.openOrCreateDatabase(mDB1Path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        String attachsql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " + DBNAME2;
        String attachsql2 = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " +  DBNAME3;
        mMaster.execSQL(attachsql);
        mMaster.execSQL(attachsql2);

        String sqlstr = "SELECT " +
                DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + ".*, " +
                DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + DB2_COL_NAME +
                ", " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + DB2_COL_NAME +
                " FROM " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =  " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =  " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN;

        Log.d("SELECTSQL_1",sqlstr);
        Cursor csr = mMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + csr.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + csr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + csr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }

        String arg1 = "12";
        String arg2 = "Fred";

        String sqlstr2 = " SELECT " +
                DB2_FULL_IDCOL + ", " +
                DB2_FULL_NAMECOL + ", " +
                DB3_FULL_IDCOL + ", " +
                DB3_FULL_NAMECOL +
                " FROM " + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON   " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =    " + DB3_FULL_IDCOL +
                " WHERE " +
                DB2_FULL_IDCOL + "=? AND " +
                DB3_FULL_NAMECOL + "=?";
        Log.d("SELECTSQL_2",sqlstr2);
        Cursor csr2 = mMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr2,new String[]{arg1,arg2});

        while (csr2.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + csr2.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr2.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + csr2.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + csr2.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }
    }

    private String createDatbase(String dbqualifier) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbqualifier,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        String tblcrtstr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE +
                "(" +
                ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE  + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(tblcrtstr);
        String rv = db.getPath();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private void insertRow(String dbqualifier, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbqualifier,MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE, name);
        db.insert(dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

You problem is that it cannot open the database db2, perhaps because of the path being incorrect. The above gets the path according to the database name.

Example output from the above (note 2nd query purposefully results in empty cursor, it is an example of coping with multiple columns named _id) :-

```
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/SELECTSQL_1: SELECT db1_table_main.*, db2.db2_table_main.db2_name, db3.db2_table_main.db2_name FROM db1_table_main JOIN db2.db2_table_main ON db1_table_main._id =  db2.db2_table_main._id JOIN db3.db2_table_main ON db1_table_main._id =  db3.db2_table_main._id
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/CSRINFO: Row = 0 Column = _id Value = 1 Column = db1_name Value = Alan Column = db2_name Value = Fred Column = db2_name Value = Fred
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/CSRINFO: Row = 1 Column = _id Value = 2 Column = db1_name Value = George Column = db2_name Value = Bert Column = db2_name Value = Bert
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/CSRINFO: Row = 2 Column = _id Value = 3 Column = db1_name Value = Robert Column = db2_name Value = Harry Column = db2_name Value = Harry
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/CSRINFO: Row = 3 Column = _id Value = 4 Column = db1_name Value = Colin Column = db2_name Value = Tom Column = db2_name Value = Tom
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/CSRINFO: Row = 4 Column = _id Value = 5 Column = db1_name Value = Ian Column = db2_name Value = Dick Column = db2_name Value = Dick
12-07 19:32:26.764 2913-2913/mjt.attachdatabases D/SELECTSQL_2:  SELECT db2.db2_table_main._id, db2.db2_table_main.db2_name, db3.db2_table_main._id, db3.db2_table_main.db2_name FROM db2_table_main JOIN db3.db2_table_main ON   db2.db2_table_main._id =    db3.db2_table_main._id WHERE db2.db2_table_main._id=? AND db3.db2_table_main.db2_name=?
```

#### Amended Code

tested on  3 devices API's 16, 23 and 24 with default permissions.
Now uses databases from different directories.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DBNAME1 = "db1";
    public static final String DBNAME2 = "db2";
    public static final String DBNAME3 = "db3";
    public static final String ID_COLUMN = "_id";
    public static final String TABLENAME_BASE = "_table_main";
    public static final String NAMECOLUMN_BASE = "_name";
    public static final String DB2_COL_NAME = DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;
    public static final String EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME = DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE;
    public static final String EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME = DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE;
    public static final String DB2_FULL_IDCOL = EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME + "." + ID_COLUMN;
    public static final String DB2_FULL_NAMECOL = EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME + "." + DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;
    public static final String DB3_FULL_IDCOL = EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME + "." + ID_COLUMN;
    public static final String DB3_FULL_NAMECOL = EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME + "." + DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;

    private static final String[] DB1NAMES = new String[] {"Fred","Bert","Harry","Tom","Dick"};
    private static final String[] DB2NAMES = new String[] {"Alan","George","Robert","Colin","Ian","John"};

    private static final String altbasepath = "/data/data/mjt.attachdatabases/";

    String mDB1Path, mDB2path, mDBA1Path, mDBA2Path;
    SQLiteDatabase mMaster, mAltMaster;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB1Path = createDatbase(DBNAME1);
        mDB2path = createDatbase(DBNAME2);
        mDBA1Path = createDatabase(DBNAME1,altbasepath);
        mDBA2Path = createDatabase(DBNAME2,altbasepath);


        // Only uncomment for first run to populate database tables
        for (String s: DB2NAMES) {
            insertRow(DBNAME1,s);
            insertAltRow(DBNAME2,s);
        }
        for (String s: DB1NAMES) {
            insertRow(DBNAME2,s);
            insertAltRow(DBNAME1,s);
        }
        Log.d("DBPATHS", "DB1 Path=" + mDB1Path + " - DSB2 path=" + mDB2path);
        Log.d("DBPATHS", "ADB1 Path=" + mDBA1Path + " - DADB2 path=" + mDBA2Path);

        mMaster = this.openOrCreateDatabase(mDB1Path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mAltMaster = this.openOrCreateDatabase(mDBA1Path,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        /*
        String altattachsql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDBA2Path + "' AS " + DBNAME2;
        String attachsql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " + DBNAME2;
        String aaltttachsql2 = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " +  DBNAME3;
        String attachsql2 = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " +  DBNAME3;
        mMaster.execSQL(attachsql);
        mMaster.execSQL(attachsql2);
        mAltMaster.execSQL(altattachsql);
        mAltMaster.execSQL(aaltttachsql2);
        */
        String mdattachsql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDBA2Path + "' AS " + DBNAME2;
        String mdattachsql2 = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDBA2Path + "' AS " + DBNAME3;
        mMaster.execSQL(mdattachsql);
        mMaster.execSQL(mdattachsql2);

        String sqlstr = "SELECT " +
                DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + ".*, " +
                DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + DB2_COL_NAME +
                ", " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + DB2_COL_NAME +
                " FROM " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =  " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =  " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN;

        Log.d("SELECTSQL_1",sqlstr);
        Cursor csr = mMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + csr.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + csr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + csr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }

        /*
        Log.d("SELECTSQL_ALT",sqlstr);
        Cursor acsr = mAltMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
        while (acsr.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + acsr.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < acsr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + acsr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + acsr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }
        */

        String arg1 = "12";
        String arg2 = "Fred";

        String sqlstr2 = " SELECT " +
                DB2_FULL_IDCOL + ", " +
                DB2_FULL_NAMECOL + ", " +
                DB3_FULL_IDCOL + ", " +
                DB3_FULL_NAMECOL +
                " FROM " + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON   " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =    " + DB3_FULL_IDCOL +
                " WHERE " +
                DB2_FULL_IDCOL + "=? AND " +
                DB3_FULL_NAMECOL + "=?";
        Log.d("SELECTSQL_2",sqlstr2);
        Cursor csr2 = mMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr2,new String[]{arg1,arg2});

        while (csr2.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + csr2.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr2.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + csr2.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + csr2.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }
    }

    private String createDatbase(String dbqualifier) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbqualifier,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        String tblcrtstr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE +
                "(" +
                ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE  + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(tblcrtstr);
        String rv = db.getPath();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private String createDatabase(String dbqualifier, String altpath) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(altpath + "/" + dbqualifier,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String tblcrtstr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE +
                "(" +
                ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE  + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(tblcrtstr);
        String rv = db.getPath();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private void insertRow(String dbqualifier, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbqualifier,MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE, name);
        db.insert(dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }

    private void insertAltRow(String dbqualifier, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(altbasepath + "/" + dbqualifier, MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE, name);
        db.insert(dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

### Attempts to recreate the same error :-

#### 1 - Try to open with a path that has a non-existing file :-

Changed code to :-

```
mAltMaster = this.openOrCreateDatabase(mDBA1Path+"x",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

Fails trying to open :-

```
12-08 06:03:31.294 1482-1482/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-08 06:03:31.294 1482-1482/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30174: (21) open(/data/data/mjt.attachdatabases/db1x) - 
12-08 06:03:31.294 1482-1482/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/mjt.attachdatabases/db1x'.
                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

#### 2 - Skip the open and try to attach with non-existing file :-

e.g. `ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/mjt.attachdatabases/db2blah' AS db2`

The ATTACH works but fails later due to table not found (i.e. the database is created, as attach appears to use openOrCreate, but has no user defined tables).

#### 3 - try to attach a database that is not a database file, in this case a pdf file renamed to db2blah.

The ATTACH fails with :-

```
E/SQLiteLog: (26) statement aborts at 5: [ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/mjt.attachdatabases/db2blah' AS db2] file is encrypted or is not a database
```

All the above appear to not meet the error. So perhaps the issue is that the database file doesn't have the appropriate permissions, another possibility is that the file may be in use.

Comment: The difference between your code and my code is that, in your code you are creating the databases and getting the path from them. In my case, the dbs are already created, i know the path and i want to just query them. The directories of the two dbs are also different. The path is correct since it works in the command line sqlite3.

Comment: @roger If you took  the care to look at the code, you should see that database creation is in fact a moot point. Only on the first run does it create the databases. On subsequent runs, when the databases exist, i.e. your situation, then it simply returns the correct path assuming that the database name is valid, the database exists and is correctly located.

Comment: Also if you carefully considered the code provided you you could easily use it to determine the accuracy of your statement :- *The path is correct since it works in the command line* (PS **BIG HINT**).

Comment: @ Mike . i see. I understand. In your code you wouldn't worry about where the db gets created right. And also i believe they would be generated in the same directory. My problem is db1 and db2 are in two different directories. So when i do     mContext.getDatabasePath("db2.db").getPath(); , it returns me the path of db1 which is wrong. And when i go see that path, i see a new db2.db created there. At this point if i am accessing any tables it errors out saying table not present. This is because the db2 which got created with  size=0 is not the one i was looking for.

Comment: @Roger *I understand. In your code you wouldn't worry about where the db gets created right* -  I would personally create them in the recommended location by default. i.e /data/data/package_name/databases. However, a few changes (as per edited answer) and it's easy to have databases in different directories. I would guess that removing /data/data/com.stack.test/databases/db2.db, would simply resort back to the code14 -  unknown error. I don't believe that this is a permissions issue at least directory wise. I've run the modified code in the answer on  on 4.1.1, 6.0.0 and 7.0.0 devices.