# Create and read from snapshot in Android Room Databse

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I need to create a snapshot of my DB and set some queries to read from it. I am aware of this method `sqlite3_snapshot_get` (ref: [sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/snapshot_get.html)) but I have no idea how to make use of it in android. No idea what to pass there via arguments. Tried many combinations such as:

```
val query = db.compileStatement("sqlite3_snapshot_get(database, \"database-shm\", \$snap1);")
```

or this:

```
val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery("sqlite3_snapshot_get(database, \"database-shm\", \$snap1);")
db.query(query)
```

But those attempts always ended with error `E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "sqlite3_snapshot_get": syntax error`. So I have already fallen on the first step, after setting a proper snapshot I still need to read from it (setup some Dao queries to read from it). Is there any proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is that normally the `SQLITE_ENABLE_SNAPSHOT` compile time option is turned off and hence the syntax error as the snapshot statements are unavailable.

- Typically unsupported statements result in a syntax error.

If you refer to https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_snapshot you will see this option is listed in the section

> 7. Options To Enable Features Normally Turned Off

To utilise the snapshot statements you would need a version of SQLite compiled with `SQLITE_ENABLE_SNAPSHOT`, this is unlikely to be available in the version distributed with Android and hence room. However you may wish to refer to https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/install.wiki which could be a means of solving your problem.

---

**Additional re comment :-**

> I am trying to think about a solution for my problem and came up with
> a different idea. Is it possible to create a dynamic copy of the
> database during app lifetime? that copy would live just for about 1-2
> sec as I compare it with the newest current version db, then I would
> delete it.

I don't believe that you need to create a copy but simply use the two database files that exist in conjunction with each other.

You could make use of [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) and perform the task(s) prior to building the Room Database Instance. You could also have separate/multiple Room Database Instances.

- Here's an example that utilises `ATTACH` but not utilising room that may be of interest [Sqlite query from mutliple databases which are already existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705732/sqlite-query-from-mutliple-databases-which-are-already-existing/47706084#47706084)
- Here's an example that may be interest in that it utilises an alternative to `ATTACH` in that it utilises multiple room database instances [Room - Using external SQLites as well as internal DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495308/room-using-external-sqlites-as-well-as-internal-db/56512638#56512638)

Comment: Well, that's disappointing... In the docs they say with Room I can harness the full power of SQLite which is not true at all. Thank you for answering. I am trying to think about a solution for my problem and came up with a different idea. Is it possible to create a dynamic copy of the database during app lifetime? that copy would live just for about 1-2 sec as I compare it with the newest current version db, then I would delete it.

Comment: @shurrok perhaps https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html might be up your street. However to compare you have various options. You could attach one db to the other (no need for a copy) and when done drop the attach. Perhaps use the application_id in the header if you know changes are due (you'd only need to read 4 bytes from each header https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header).  I agree about full power and prefer to not use room. Although this isn't a room restriction it's an android built in sqlite restriction.

Comment: What do you mean by attaching one db to the other?

Comment: @shurrok https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html although long-winded, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705732/sqlite-query-from-mutliple-databases-which-are-already-existing/47706084#47706084 uses `ATTACH` and also `DETACH`, it's done on android (not room) and covers some issues with the file (database) path.

Comment: that's sad... Unfortunately, I need a room solution for my project. I need somehow to query from snapshot/copy or anything like that